# How To Check If HTML iframe Is Loading New Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display loading message when an iFrame is loading? — JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626638/how-to-display-loading-message-when-an-iframe-is-loading-jquery)

I have an `<iframe>` element in my code that I am setting the src to a third party site. This source is a search tool, so it has textboxes and a button to click to perform the search. The problem is that this search tool is very slow, so I want to display a loading message to the user after they click on the button to perform the search. Is there a way for me to detect that the `<iframe>` is currently loading new content from my page? Since the source is from a third party, I can't handle anything on button click (that I know of at least).

Comment: See the duplicate: you need to listen to the onload handler of the iframe.

Comment: The duplicate is similar, but doesn't answer the question. In this case .ready() isnt an option. I don't think there is a way to detect when the iframe begins to load a new page.

Comment: 'src to a third party site' - no way

Comment: In that example, it works for when the iframe loads its initial content. But when there is a button from the source that causes new content to load, it doesn't show the loading message anymore.

Comment: I'm going with it isn't possible unless proven otherwise. Since it's a 3rd party site, you don't have any access to it other than the onload callback.