# indicate page loading to user accessing web-app via iframe

Tags: html, iframe, web, loading

I have a web application that I have been working on. When consumed directly it is clear when a page is loading because your browser indicates as much. The issue I am having is that a client wants to display my web-app within an iframe on their site. The first time the page loads, they are able to indicate the iframe is loading, but this don't really matter as the first page of the app loads very quickly. The issue is that users can submit queries of nearly infinite complexity to the application, ad as a results so request may take many seconds to load. When viewed in the iframe it isn't clear the the user's request has been submitted and I run the risk to them trying to resubmit, or fearing they have crashed the page/their browser.

What I need is a way to have the iframe indicate the the user that new content is loading.

Any ideas? I can use an intermediate page with a loading gif. That is a solution, but I was hoping for something else as well.

Comment: saw something similar at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626638/how-to-display-loading-message-when-an-iframe-is-loading

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I believe this only works for the fist page loaded in the iframe. For my app there are buttons on the page that allow the user to trigger other processes, and these may take many seconds to return a response.