# display a loading animation for a set period of time over top of an iframe in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

How can I display a loading animation for a set period of time over top of an iframe in R Shiny?

I'm loading a large (~18 mb) html file in an iframe in a shiny app. The browser takes a couple seconds to fully load the html file. All loading animations that I can find (e.g. [shinycssloaders](https://github.com/daattali/shinycssloaders), [waiter](https://github.com/JohnCoene/waiter), [custom loading animations like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16485533/3174566)) stop displaying the animation when the iframe starts to load, but since I'm loading from a file, the iframe starts to load almost instantly, but it takes several seconds to finish loading. I want to display something over top of the iframe for several seconds to indicate to the user that the iframe is (likely) not finished loading.

Here's a shiny app that shows an iframe without any loading/waiting animation.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    shiny::fluidRow(
        shinycssloaders::withSpinner(
            shiny::uiOutput(outputId = "iframe"),
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$iframe <- shiny::renderUI({
        tags$iframe(src = "https://example.com/", style = 'width:90vw;height:90vh;')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [CSS animation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Save the following CSS code in a file **myloader.css** located in the ***www*** subfolder of the app.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Origin;
  src: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/origin-extrabold-webfont.woff);
}

.myloader {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #222;
  height: 150px;
}

.myloader > h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Origin, Helvetica Light, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 242, 181);
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    rgb(255, 242, 181) 28%,
    rgb(77, 77, 77) 40%,
    rgb(255, 242, 181) 54%
  );
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
}

.myloader > h1 > span::before {
  content: "";
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    content: "Loading";
  }
  10% {
    content: "Loading.";
  }
  20% {
    content: "Loading..";
  }
  30% {
    content: "Loading...";
  }
  40% {
    content: "Loading....";
  }
  50% {
    content: "Loading.....";
  }
  60% {
    content: "Loading......";
  }
  70% {
    content: "Loading.......";
  }
  80% {
    content: "Loading........";
  }
  90% {
    content: "Loading.........";
  }
  100% {
    content: "Almost there!";
  }
}
```

We will need JavaScript to remove the animation when it is finished:

```r
js <- '
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myloader > h1 > span").on(
    "animationend",
    function() {
        $(".myloader").remove();
    }
  );
});
'
```

Here is the Shiny app:

```r
library(shiny)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myloader > h1 > span").on(
    "animationend",
    function() {
        $(".myloader").remove();
    }
  );
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "myloader.css")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    tags$div(
      class = "myloader",
      tags$h1(
        tags$span()
      )
    ),
    tags$iframe(src = "https://example.com/", style = 'width:90vw; height:90vh;')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor modification of [Stephane Laurent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77929639/3174566) to allow the loading animation to be re-loaded when the iframe is reloaded.

CSS code saved in **myloader.css** file located in the **www** subfolder of the app:

```css
.myloader {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255); /* rgb(255,50,50);*/
  height: 60px;
}

.myloader > h1 {
  position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Origin, Helvetica Light, sans-serif;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
}

.myloader > h1 > span::before {
  content: "";
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    content: url("1487.gif");
  }
}
```

**1487.gif** downloaded from https://icons8.com/preloaders/ and saved in the **www** directory.

Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myloader > h1 > span").on(
    "animationend",
    function() {
        $(".myloader").remove();
    }
  );
});
'

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
    
    shiny::titlePanel(
        shiny::fluidRow(
            shiny::column(
                width = 12, 
                align="center",
                "My Title")
        )
    ),
    shiny::mainPanel( width = 12,
                      shiny::fluidRow(
                          shiny::column(
                              width = 12,
                              align = "center",
                              shiny::selectInput(
                                  inputId = 'website', 
                                  label = shiny::h5("Select page"), 
                                  choices = c('Example', 'Wikipedia'), 
                                  selected = 'Example', 
                                  multiple = F
                              )
                          )
                      ),
                      shiny::fluidRow(
                          shiny::htmlOutput("iframe")
                      )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    url_reactive <- shiny::reactive({
        switch(input$website,
               'Example' = "https://example.com/",
               'Wikipedia' = "https://www.wikipedia.org/",
               stop("input website invalid"))
        
    })
    
    output$iframe <- shiny::renderUI({
        list(
            tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js)), tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "myloader.css")),
            tags$div(class = "myloader", tags$h1(tags$span())),
            tags$iframe(src = url_reactive(), style = 'width:96vw;height:100vh;')
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The end result:
[image]